# How do I make my web service so it can be authenticated using basic authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

I have a web service in asmx e.g.

```
public void Create(classA objA)
{
   //Some code here
}
```

Now the client has asked me to make it work with Basic Authentication.

I did this.

```
public Credentials Credentials;

[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("Credentials")]
public void Create(classA objA)
{
   //Some code here

   Call a method to check a username and password with the database.

}
```

The credentials class:

```
public class Credentials:SoapHeader
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public Credentials()
    {

    }}
```

But the client says that they don't want it, it requires them to pass extra parameters. They only want basic authentication.

So how do I make it good for basic authentication?

and how would the client authenticate it using basic authentication?